# How to keep the order by updating OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.5, ordereddictionary

please tell me.

**Description**

I'd like to update the value of a variable of type `OrderedDict` by using the update method of dict.
However, after executing the update method, the `OrderedDict` type of the update target variable is lost, and output as expected can not be done.

**Question points:**

1. Is it faulty to lose the type of `OrderedDict`?
2. Is there another way to update dict while keeping the type of `OrderedDict`?

Below is an example of the problem.

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = OrderedDict()

dic['a'] = 1
dic['b'] = OrderedDict()
dic['b']['b1'] = 2
dic['b']['b2'] = 3
dic['b']['b3'] = 4

print(dic)
> OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', OrderedDict([('b1', 2), ('b2', 3), ('b3', 4)]))]) # ok

new_dic = {'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5}}
print(new_dic)
> {'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5}}

dic.update(new_dic)

print(dic)
> OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5})]) # NG: Type has been lost
```

---

Comment: I appreciate your answers.

I used this site for the first time, but I was surprised very quickly.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update has the effect of a rebinding of the affected keys. What you are doing in short, is:

```
# ...
dic['b'] = OrderedDict()
# ...
dic['b'] = {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5}
# ...
```

The new value of key `'b'` in `dic` is now the common `dict`. You are trying to do some nested update that is not provided out of the box. You could implement it yourself along the lines of:

```
def update(d1, d2):
    for k, v in d2.items():
        if k in d1 and isinstance(v, dict) and isinstance(d1[k], dict):
            update(d1[k], v)
        else:
            d1[k] = v
```

Now you can apply it to your case:

```
update(dic, new_dic)
# OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', OrderedDict([('b1', 3), ('b2', 4), ('b3', 5)]))])
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
new_dic = {'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5}}
```

to

```
new_dic = {'a': 2, 'b': OrderedDict([('b1', 3), ('b2', 4), ('b3', 5)])}
```

It'd be okay!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dic = OrderedDict()

dic['a'] = 1
dic['b'] = OrderedDict()
dic['b']['b1'] = 2
dic['b']['b2'] = 3
dic['b']['b3'] = 4

print(dic)
#> OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', OrderedDict([('b1', 2), ('b2', 3), ('b3', 4)]))]) # ok

new_dic = {'a': 2, 'b': {'b1': 3, 'b2': 4, 'b3': 5}}
new_dic['b'] = OrderedDict(new_dic['b'])
print(new_dic)
#> {'a': 2, 'b': OrderedDict([('b1', 3), ('b2', 4), ('b3', 5)])}    
dic.update(new_dic)

print(dic)
#> OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', OrderedDict([('b1', 3), ('b2', 4), ('b3', 5)]))])
```